# gdb error: Could not open file result for a specific breakpoint

Tags: debugging, gdb

Trying to debug file using gdb. The file is compiled but whenever i set a specific break point it tells me:

```
(gdb) b big_thing
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1270: file Q1.c, line 19.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/kali/Downloads/Q1t 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Could not open file
[Inferior 1 (process 195948) exited normally]
```

Although the program is compiled using "-g" and using a 32-compiler. Every other breakpoint works fine except this one.

Answer (score 0):

This message: `Could not open file` comes from your own program. Your program exits before reaching the breakpoint, so everything appears to work as intended here.

Consider this example:

```
int foo() { return 42; }
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) exit(0);
  return foo();
}
```

If you set a breakpoint on `foo` and run the program as `./a.out` (i.e. without arguments), the program will exit without hitting the breakpoint (just as is happening with your `Q1.c`).